# Pass derived class to API method in place of base class

Tags: c#, api, inheritance

I am trying to write an API method that accepts a base class, in order to allow multiple different derived classes to be passed in, such as ...

```
//Classes in program
public abstract class Game
{
    public int NoOfPlayers {get; set;}
}

public class Chess : Game
{
    public int SquaresOnBoard {get; set;}
    public bool KingInCheck {get; set;}
    public Color ColorToMove {get; set;}

    public Chess(){...}
}

public class Uno : Game
{
    public int CardsInDeck {get;set;}
    public Color CurrentColor {get;set}
    public int CurrentNumber {get; set;}

    public Uno() {...}
}

//API method
[Route(BaseRoute+"startGame"), HttpPost]
public ApiResponse StartGame(Game gameToStart)
{
    if (gameToStart is Uno) {...}
    else if (gameToStart is Chess) {...}
}
```

The issue is that gameToStart is always null, even though I know data is getting passed in. I believe (but I don't know for sure) that this is because my code is expecting something that looks like the signature of Game, not something with the properties of Uno or Chess.

Is there a way to accomplish this (using a parameter of type Game but passing in something that matches the properties of Uno or Chess)?

Potentially useful info: The API is powered by MVC.NET API.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are using a HttpGet. This by definition does not send data. 
Just maybe you are looking to use a HttpPost?

Comment: Sorry. Should have been Post. (It is post in the real code) This is what happens when you try to SO on mobile lol

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance of your classes is correct but you forgot concept of `Upcasting` and `DownCasting` for more information see: [here](http://www.interviewsansar.com/2016/04/23/up-casting-and-down-casting-in-csharp-interview-qa/)

Attention that the `Game` class maybe was a Chess or Uno but the `Chess` or `Uno` probably are Game. when you pass object of `Game` class to your method, never can that Game is Uno or no!

I think the best way is that your have to create a meddle class and use of them to check your game.